# Problema para diagramar divs

Tags: html, css

Problema para diagramar divs
favorito
Preciso passar como divs verde e rosa pra baixo das azuis escuro e claro, deixando uma div maior ao lado de todas, mas não sei como trabalhar isso no CSS. Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Abaixo meus códigos de html e css:

```css
#forma{
  width:960px;
  height:930px;
  background-color:#000;    
  margin:auto;
  align:center;
}
#nav1{
    width: 480px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#DFF034;
    float: left;
}
#nav2{
    width: 480px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#50E53F;
    float: left;
}
#banner{
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #3028E9;
}
#body1{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #2DD58A;
    float: left;
}
#body2{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #020635;
    float: left;
}
#body3{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #1A6AE5;
    float: left;
}
#corner{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
#incorner1{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #050421;
    float: left;
}
#incorner2{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#B4C5CD;
    float: left;
}
#incorner3{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #37CB44;
    float: left;
}
#incorner4{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #DC8082;
    float: left;
}
#bigcorner{
    width: 640px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #AC8329;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>layout2</title>
<link style="text/css" href="css/estilo2.css"
rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="forma">
    <div id="nav1"></div>
    <div id="nav2"></div>
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="body1"></div>
    <div id="body2"></div>
    <div id="body3"></div>
    <div corner>
        <div id="incorner1"></div>
        <div id="incorner2"></div>
        <div id="incorner3"></div>
        <div id="incorner4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bigcorner"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor. Não entendi.

Comment: Eu tenho uma div corner quadrada onde coloquei quatro divs quadradas dentro. E do lado quero por uma div retangular. Mas os quatro incorner estão ficando alinhados e empurrando o retângulo bigcorner pra baixo. Queria dois incorner em cima e dois embaixo dentro da forma, mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 0):

## Faltou nomear o id="conner"

Pelo o que analisei, você já tinha feito a flutuação que precisa.

Só tinha esquecido de nomear o **id="conner"**

### Dicas

Um conselho para você trabalhar melhor e poder reutilizar sua estrutura é usar **class="class" .class** ao invés de **id** em sua estrutura.
**id** só se usa quando for elementos únicos como formulários ou em algum elemento que necessite ter sua identificação única.
Usando **class** você pode reutilizar sua estrutura sem demais problemas e será mais feliz.

### Grid

Algo que pode te ajudar a melhorar seus projetos também é o uso de algum framework de grid ou até mesmo criar o seu próprio.

Bootstrap tem um ótimo sistema de grid, aconselho o estudo.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Esse artigo também iria te ajudar a entender melhor como funciona um grid simples.

https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-sistemas-de-grid-css-do-zero/

Espero ter conseguido ajudar, qualquer dúvida comenta ai.

```css
#forma{
  width:960px;
  height:930px;
  background-color:#000;    
  margin:auto;
  align:center;
}
#nav1{
    width: 480px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#DFF034;
    float: left;
}
#nav2{
    width: 480px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#50E53F;
    float: left;
}
#banner{
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #3028E9;
}
#body1{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #2DD58A;
    float: left;
}
#body2{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #020635;
    float: left;
}
#body3{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #1A6AE5;
    float: left;
}
#corner{
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
#incorner1{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #050421;
    float: left;
}
#incorner2{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#B4C5CD;
    float: left;        
}
#incorner3{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #37CB44;
    float: left;
}
#incorner4{
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #DC8082;
    float: left;
}
#bigcorner{
    width: 640px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #AC8329;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>layout2</title>
<link style="text/css" href="css/estilo2.css"
rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="forma">
    <div id="nav1"></div>
    <div id="nav2"></div>
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="body1"></div>
    <div id="body2"></div>
    <div id="body3"></div>
    <div id="corner">
        <div id="incorner1"></div>
        <div id="incorner2"></div>
        <div id="incorner3"></div>
        <div id="incorner4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bigcorner"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```